# Why action is not going through reducer?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to pull posts from WordPress blog.

In console, I am only getting one log for `Blog` component where `this.props.posts` is empty object. It should have second log when state changes after action passes through the reducer. I can even see successful xhr request for the posts in inspector.

Following is the component where I am firing action.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {fetchPosts} from '../../action/index';
class Blog extends Component {

    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.fetchPosts();
    }

    render(){
        console.log('Posts are: ',this.props.posts);
        return (
            <div>
                <Link to="/posts/new"><button> Add a New Post </button> </Link>                
            </div>
        );
    }
}
function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
        posts: state.posts
    };
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchPosts})(Blog);
```

Following is the reducer.

```
import FETCH_POSTS from '../action';
import _ from 'lodash';

function PostsReducer(state= {}, action){
    switch(action.type){

        case FETCH_POSTS:
        console.log('reducer: ', action.payload.data);
        return _.mapKeys(action.payload.data, 'id');


        default:
        return state;
    }
}

export default PostsReducer;
```

Index file for the combined reducer is following:

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import PostsReducer from './posts_reducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    posts: PostsReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Here's the action creator file

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const FETCH_POSTS = 'fetch_posts';

const ROOT_URL = 'https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/sites/ishhaanpatel.wordpress.com/posts';

export function fetchPosts() {

    const request = axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}`);

    console.log('request is: ',request);

    return {
        type: FETCH_POSTS,
        payload: request
    };

}
export default fetchPosts;
```

Comment: You're missing braces in this statement: `import FETCH_POSTS from '../action'`.  It's not the default export.

Comment: Thanks @Andy, so should I embed `FETCH_POSTS` in curly braces?

Comment: I just tried curly braces and now I am not getting even one console log.

Comment: I just restarted my application and now not getting any console log without braces too.

Comment: I believe you'll also need to `import fetchPosts from '../action'` in your component, in order for `connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchPosts})(Blog)` to connect to it

Comment: Or `import { fetchPosts } from '../action'`. It looks like you're exporting that function both as a default and as a named export. I'd recommend you pick just one of those and stick with it

Comment: @hamms, thanks but it was already there I didn't post it here. Any other thoguhts?

Comment: @IshanPatel Are you using redux-promise-middleware?

Comment: @kakamg0, nope I am not using redux-promise

Comment: You are returning the promise inside the `payload` field, not the response data. You might want to use [`redux-thunk`](https://medium.com/@stowball/a-dummys-guide-to-redux-and-thunk-in-react-d8904a7005d3) if you want to make asynchronous requests inside your actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your action is asynchronous, so you need to dispatch it through some middle-ware like [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk). See ["Async Actions"](https://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html) in the official docs.

When you dispatch a plain action you can simply return the object literal, like this:

```
const actionCreator = () => ({ type: 'ACTION' })
```

but you want to attach a response payload to your action, so you need to wait until the request promise resolves and (if you are using thunks) **return a function that takes dispatch as argument, which returns the actual action payload**:

```
const asyncActionCreator = () => dispatch => {
  fetch('url')
  .then(response => dispatch({type: 'ACTION', payload: response}))
}
```

See above links for a deeper explanation and examples.

// edit

In case you are unfamiliar with the ES6 syntax:

```
function asyncActionCreator() {
  return function(dispatch) {
    fetch('url')
    .then(function(response) {
      dispatch({type: 'ACTION', payload: response})
    })
  }
}
```